# Reading first N lines of file on FTP server in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, bytesio

I have a CSV file on an FTP server. The file is around 200mb.

For now, I am reading the file using the following method, the issue with this implementation is that the file takes too long to download, the `retrbinary` method takes around 12min to execute. I tried with different block sizes, I was able to get the time to 11 min which is still too much.

```
download_file = io.BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary("RETR {}".format(file_path),download_file.write, 8024)
download_file.seek(0)
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(download_file, nrows=4)
```

I need help reading the file in chunks, I only need the first 4 rows of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To read the first 4 lines of a remote file only, use:

```
download_file = io.BytesIO()

ftp.sendcmd('TYPE A')
conn = ftp.transfercmd("RETR {}".format(file_path))
fp = conn.makefile('rb')
count = 0
while count < 4:
    line = fp.readline(ftp.maxline + 1)
    if not line:
        break
    download_file.write(line)
    count += 1
fp.close()
conn.close()
```

---

Had you really wanted to process the *whole file in chunks*, it would be way more complicated, given the API of ftplib and Pandas. But it is possible. For some ideas, see: [Get files names inside a zip file on FTP server without downloading whole archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53143518/850848).