# Open image on ftp server with PIL

Tags: python, ftp, python-imaging-library

I have many images stored in an ftp server.

I would like to avoid downloading all the images, but just load them from the ftp using PIL, like that:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("ftp://myftp.com/dir/myimage.bmp")
```

It does not work this way (No such file or directory).

How can I do this without downloading in a temporary file ?

I am using python 3.8.

Comment: Could you please add the Python version that you are using into your question? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to read the file, you need to download it - but not necessarily save it locally.

Comment: Can you please give me an example @MauriceMeyer

Comment: @dagnic: Use BytesIO, as mentioned there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990046/retrieve-data-from-gz-file-on-ftp-server-without-writing-it-locally

Answer (score 2):

Following @MauriceMeyer, I did the following, that works.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("myftp.com")
ftp.login("me", "mypwd")
flo = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR dir/myimage.bmp', flo.write)
flo.seek(0)
img = Image.open(flo)
```